# Add to Linked List in sorted order, having trouble with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to create a method which will add a char* to a LinkedList,  ensuring that the linkedList is always sorted alphabetically. I have been given code to define a LinkedItem struct:

```
// Define our list item as 'struct ListItem', and also 
// typedef it under the same name.
typedef struct ListItem {
  char *s;
  struct ListItem *p_next;
} ListItem;
```

I have also been given a method to add an item to the beginning of a list:

```
// Adds a new item to the beginning of a list, returning the new
// item (ie the head of the new list *)
ListItem* add_item(ListItem *p_head, char *s) {  
    // Allocate some memory for the size of our structure.
    ListItem *p_new_item = malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
    p_new_item->p_next = p_head;       // We are the new tail.
    p_new_item->s = s;     // Set data pointer. 
    return p_new_item;
}
```

Now here's my code, I'll explain more after:

```
ListItem* addSortedItem(ListItem *p_head, char *s){         
    if(p_head==NULL)//if the list is empty, we add to the beginning
        return add_item(p_head,s);
    ListItem* p_new_item = malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
    ListItem *p_current_item = p_head; //makes a pointer to the head of the list


    while (p_current_item) {    // Loop while the current pointer is not NULL
        printf("entering while loop with current=%s\n",p_current_item->s);
        // now we want to look at the value contained and compare it to the value input     
        if(aThenB(s,p_current_item->s)!=TRUE){
            // if A goes after B, we want to go on to look at the next element
            p_current_item=p_current_item->p_next;
        } else if (aThenB(s,p_current_item->s)==TRUE) {printf("entered elseif\n");      
            p_head=add_item(p_current_item,s);
            return p_head;          
        } else {printf("WHY DID WE EVER REACH THE ELSE!?"); return p_head;}
    }
}
```

Now, aThenB(StringA,StringB) returns TRUE if the correct sorted order of A and B is A, then B, and false otherwise- equality is also an option, I simply haven't gotten this to work well enough to allow that :-)

What is happening with my test data (which is `"sheep i"`, with i from 0-10) is that either I am only returning one element back, or i am randomly skipping elements, depending on the order input. I can include more code but it's a bit messy.

I think my problem is stemming from not fully understanding the pointers and how they work- I want to ensure that p_head is always pointing to the head, whilst p_current is roving through the list. But I'm also getting seg faults when p_current reaches the last element, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thank you for any help on how to get my code to return properly :-)

Edit: addSortedItem() is called in the following block in the main method:

```
    // The empty list is represented by a pointer to NULL.
    ListItem *p_head = NULL;
    ListItem *p_head2=NULL;
    // Now add some items onto the beginning of the list.
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NO_ITEMS; i++) {

    // Allocate some memory for our string, and use snprintf to
    // create a formatted string (see GNU API docs) much like printf
    // but instead writing to memory rather than the screen.
    char* s = malloc(MAX_DATA_CHARS);
    snprintf(s, (size_t) MAX_DATA_CHARS, "sheep %d", i);
    p_head = addSortedItem(p_head, s);
    }
```

Comment: it compares the two parameters (stringA and stringB), one character at a time, and returns `FALSE (0) if stringB<stringA; TRUE (1) if stringA<stringB;` 
stringA==stringB is a separate case which I've got a function equals(StringA,StringB) for, that returns TRUE if they are equal.

Comment: Please include the code that calls `addSortedItem`. There are plenty of opportunities to mess things up there, because of the way the function transfers ownership of the string to the linked list.

Comment: added it above :-) bit of trouble formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in the add of a new element in the middle or in the end of the linked list. 
in your `addStoredItem` function you make a pointer from your newItem to the currentItem but you do not take account to have a link from previous element  to the newItem

initial linked list befor calling `addStoredItem`

```
item1-->item2-->item4-->item5
```

Linked list afetr calling `addStoredItem` in order to add **item3**

```
item1-->item2-->item4-->item5
                ^
                |
                item3
```

so as you can see you have added the new item at the head of the sub linked list starting from **item4** but you do not make link from **item2** to **item3**
so that we have to keep a pointer to the previous item in order to complete the link.

the `add_item()` function allow to add item in the head

The same thing if you try to add item at the end of the linked list

```
item1-->item2-->item4-->item5    NULL
                                 ^
                                 |
                                 item6
```

the **item6** has added as separate head and there is no link from **item5** (previous) to item6 (new)

so your `addStoredItem()` function could be fixed like this

```
ListItem* addSortedItem(ListItem *p_head, char *s){         
    if(p_head==NULL)//if the list is empty, we add to the beginning
        return add_item(p_head,s);
    struct ListItem* p_new_item = malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
    ListItem *p_current_item = p_head; //makes a pointer to the head of the list
    ListItem *p_prev_item = NULL; //FIXED

    while (p_current_item) {    // Loop while the current pointer is not NULL
        printf("entering while loop with current=%s\n",p_current_item->s);
        // now we want to look at the value contained and compare it to the value input     
        if(aThenB(s,p_current_item->s)!=TRUE){
            // if A goes after B, we want to go on to look at the next element
            p_prev_item = p_current_item; //FIXED
            p_current_item=p_current_item->p_next;
        } else if (aThenB(s,p_current_item->s)==TRUE) {printf("entered elseif\n");      
            break;        
        } else {printf("WHY DID WE EVER REACH THE ELSE!?"); return p_head;}
    }

    if (p_prev_item!=NULL) //FIXED
        p_prev_item->p_next=add_item(p_current_item,s); //FIXED
    else //FIXED
        p_head=add_item(p_current_item,s);//FIXED
    return p_head; //FIXED
}
```

the fixed lines are indicated with `//FIXED`

Comment: Can you explain the line `p_prev_item->p_next=add_item(p_current_item,s);`?
I've tried implementing this (blindly) and it works but i'm a bit confused what is actually happening. Here's what my understanding of pointers says:
the first arrow means that we are dealing with a pointer to the pointer contained in the p_prev_item struct; which i believe is a similar idea to a double pointer (**p). before that line, `p_prev->p_next = current_item` (by definition); so why can't we just change what current_item is by saying `p_current_item=add_item(p_current_item,s);`

Comment: Thanks! :-) there's still an issue with it- it's still unable to put things in the middle properly. But I'm going to give it a go to work myself on that issue first :-)

Answer (score 0):

At first, your `p_head` is `NULL`, so when you enter your `addSortedItem` function you create the list and add the first string. That's alright.
But then, upon adding the second item (which in your case is "sheep 1"), you enter your `while (p_current_item)` loop. The call to `aThenB` returns `FALSE` and you go to your next element which is.. `NULL`! Indeed, at this time, `p_head` looks like this:

```
p_head {
s = "sheep 0",
p_next = NULL
}
```

Your `while` condition is not true and you exit your function, nothing was added.
You could add a condition in your first `if` like:

```
if (p_current_item->next == NULL)
  p_current_item->next = addSortedItem(NULL, s);
else
  p_current_item = p_current_item->next;
```

Also, saying that `p_head=add_item(p_current_item,s);` is wrong. Suppose your list is something like:

```
"sheep 1" -> "sheep 2" -> "sheep 4" -> "sheep 5"
```

If you add "sheep 3", you will get this:

```
"sheep 1" -> "sheep 2" -> "sheep 3" -> "sheep 4" -> "sheep 5"
                          ^
                          |
                          p_head
```

You won't be able to add "sheep 0" anymore. Don't return the return value of `addSortedItem` as the new `p_head`

Comment: I didn't know I could pass a null parameter. ... That would then make p_current->next be the head of a new list, the head of which contains s and the second(tail) element of which is null?

Answer (score 0):

Support stuff:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#define aThenB(a,b) (strcmp(a,b) <=0 ? TRUE : FALSE)
```

All the special cases can be avoided by modifying the function's signature to
accept a pointer to pointer.

```
void addSortedItem(ListItem **pp_head, char *s){         
    ListItem *p_new_item ;

    for (       ;*pp_head; pp_head = &(*pp_head)->p_next) {    
        if (aThenB(s,(*pp_head)->s)==FALSE) break;
    }

    p_new_item = malloc(sizeof *p_new_item);
    p_new_item->s = s;

    p_new_item->p_next = *pp_head;
    *pp_head = p_new_item;
}
```

The caller should do:

```
ListItem *root = NULL;
addSortedItem( &root, "sheep#0");
```

Comment: this is a bit over my head. What goes into the blank section of the `for` declaration?

Comment: Nothing. The for() loop just starts with the **p_head (the first argument to the function). *pp_head==NULL signifies the end of the list. (which could mean: the beginning of an empty list)

Comment: ah. so its the same idea as  while(*p_head): if *pp_head is null, then the while loop exits; this way we increment in the next bit. so `pp_head=&(*pp_head)->p_next)` is saying that the pp_head argument (which is a double pointer) is now going to point itself to the address that ... no i don't understand. Again, the pointers are really confusing me still. I have a background in Java so this is really my first time working with them.

Comment: Use pencil and paper: The whole net effect of the insertion is that *somewhere* a pointer to a ListItem should get the address of the freshly allocated ListItem object (and the fresh object will *steal* the old value). This pointer could be the head/root of the list, or a ->p_next pointer somewhere in the chain. And: to change something, you need it's address. To change a pointer, you need the address of that pointer. Ergo: pointer-to-pointer. QED.